# PHP Extract File Name

Tags: php, regex

I am basically after a method of extracting a file name from a path. The file type may change and the file name may have white space in it. Also the path may be in Unix form or Windows form.

```
/Users/Bob/Documents/some file.docx
```

Or

```
C:\Users\Bob\My Documents\some file.docx
```

The complete source path is already stored in a variable called `$fileSource` and I have the file name without the extension in a variable called `$fileName`. I have tried to use `str_replace`to replace the common part of the file source with zero space but the path may change so this is not viable.

I thought if regex could be used to work backward through the string the last (reading from left to right) \ or / but I don't really know much regex yet. I have read about a look-backward feature which should start (?<=*string*) but I can't get this to work.

Lastly The reason I need the file name with the extension is because I am using PHP to copy it from one location to another and if I don't have the file extension the files turns up without the extension and I have to add it manually.

If what I am asking is not possible I guess I could just use regex to get the file extension and then concatenate that to the `$fileName` but I am hoping for something more graceful.

Cheers.

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function, it is there for exectly this purpose

Comment: +1 for [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

Comment: Check the PHP Manual at [basename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

Comment: True, $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); would be the slickest IMHO.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve; does `basename($fileSource)` work? If not, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's incredible simple to use [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$fileName = pathinfo($fileSource, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
```

..or simply [`basename`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

```
$fileName = basename($fileSource);
```

**Do note**: Windows paths will not work correctly on linux servers and linux paths will not work correctly on windows servers (due to `DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR` being different).

[**DEMO on  a linux server**](http://codepad.org/1Lx2fpf6)

Comment: @Jack Correct - added info to the answer.

Comment: @Jack Except the extension is added. Surely you could do `basename($fileSource) . '.' . pathinfo($fileSource, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` but you'd be calling 2 functions instead of 1, and readability wouldn't be any easier (in my opinion), so hence why I used but one call to `pathinfo` :)

Comment: Though if you're using < 5.2, you really should upgrade.... even if you're using 5.2.x, you really should upgrade

Comment: ^ This. The reason I didn't add it in my answer is that some people simply *can't* upgrade due to different reasons. Anything from no-access-servers and crappy programmed software could result in you not being able to go past 5.1.

Comment: @Jack PATHINFO_FILENAME doesn't strip the extension. `basename` would be "document", `extension` would be `doc` and `filename` would be `document.doc`. [Check the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php). **Edit**: Oh wow - maybe **I** should check the manual. Fixing the answer.

Comment: Looks like pathinfo will do exactly what i need it to. Will give ago this evening. Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) is specifically for this:

**Examples:**

```
$file = pathinfo($yourFile, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

$file_ext = strtolower(pathinfo($yourFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); //gets the file extension
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (alternative to pathinfo):

```
<?php
$filePath = '/Users/Bob/Documents/some file.docx'; // using *nix here
$file     = end(explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $filePath));

echo $file;
```

In case you worry about paths without a filename (so a directory path), then use this:

```
<?php
$filePath = '/Users/Bob/Documents/some file.docx'; // using *nix here
$DS       = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; // this way you can handle WinOS and *NIX paths
$file     = end(explode($DS, trim($filePath, $DS));

// Check if the path contains a dot, so it's a file name 
// with extension (e.g. filename.php)
$file     = (strpos($file, '.') !== false) ? $file : false;

echo $file;
```